# creating a dictionary from an old one by only duplicating the keys

Tags: python

I'm wondering how can do create a kind of key_duplicated dictionary given a previously defined dictionary?

namely, Suppose we have a dictionary like this `{"qq":1,"ww":2,"ee",3}` then I want a new dictionary with the same keys and maybe some random values of the same type as the given dictionary `{"qq":0,"ww":0,"ee":0}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this one is very pythonic (also, it may be faster than dict comprehension).

```
d2 = dict.fromkeys(d1, 0)
```

Comment: It is faster than dict comprehension, you're right. This method should be used if you want to give the same value each time, dict comprehension should be used if you want to add logic to assigning the value. [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a dict comprehension:

```py
d1 = {"qq":1,"ww":2,"ee": 3}
d2 = {k: 0 for k in d1}
```